# Setting temporary environment variable for a script

Tags: python, c, unix

I am currently learning about unix and I have a question about setting temporary environment path. I have the following script in C,

```
///home/jason/Public/TestTempEnv.c
putenv("PATH=$PATH:/home/jason/Public/:/home/jason/Private/");
system("register");
```

From my understanding, it will search for 'register' in all the paths defined in $PATH starting from first defined path, left to right.

However, if I have a python script that does the following,

```
import os
os.system("export PATH=/home/lucy/:$PATH && /home/jason/Public/TestTempEnv")
```

The python script sets temporary path and then calling the `TestTempEnv.c` script, will the final path inside `TestTempEnv.c` have the `/home/lucy/` path added before it executes `register`?

Just to add that I have compiled the C script using the command,`gcc TestTempEnv.c -o TestTempEnv`

Comment: Indirect answer: You can use the strace command to see what your process does, including which directories it uses to locate stuff.

Comment: what is your question? Both constructs work even if the python version is not the most pythonic and neither are very portable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I would like to know if I the final path inside the C file will have `/home/lucy` added before it executes `register`

Comment: @Park Taecyeon If that is all: The answer is "Yes.".

Comment: But still, you should consider using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api) instead. It's portable, it allows precise control of the environment, and it avoids spawning a shell process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use execve and precise the env var: 
int execve(const char *fichier, char *const argv[], **char *const envp[]**); 
see the man